# Surf feature error in code

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

I am doing code for feature extraction using SURF , but it give me error in it here below is my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include  <vector>
#pragma comment (lib , "opencv_core244d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib ,"opencv_highgui244d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib , "opencv_imgproc244d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib ,"opencv_video244.lib")
using namespace cv ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat image1, outImg1, image2, outImg2;


    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;


    image1 = imread("1.jpg",0);
    image2 = imread("2.jpg",0);

    SurfFeatureDetector surf(2500);
    surf.detect(image1, keypoints1);
    surf.detect(image2, keypoints2);
    drawKeypoints(image1, keypoints1, outImg1, Scalar(255,255,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    drawKeypoints(image2, keypoints2, outImg2, Scalar(255,255,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    namedWindow("SURF detector img1");
    imshow("SURF detector img1", outImg1);

    namedWindow("SURF detector img2");
    imshow("SURF detector img2", outImg2);

    SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc;
    Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
    surfDesc.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    surfDesc.compute(image2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

These are the error's

```
Error2  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::DescriptorExtractor::compute(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<class cv::KeyPoint,class std::allocator<class cv::KeyPoint> > &,class cv::Mat &)const " (?compute@DescriptorExtractor@cv@@QBEXABVMat@2@AAV?$vector@VKeyPoint@cv@@V?$allocator@VKeyPoint@cv@@@std@@@std@@AAV32@@Z) referenced in function _main
Error3  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SURF::SURF(void)" (??0SURF@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
Error4  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::drawKeypoints(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<class cv::KeyPoint,class std::allocator<class cv::KeyPoint> > const &,class cv::Mat &,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &,int)" (?drawKeypoints@cv@@YAXABVMat@1@ABV?$vector@VKeyPoint@cv@@V?$allocator@VKeyPoint@cv@@@std@@@std@@AAV21@ABV?$Scalar_@N@1@H@Z) referenced in function _main
Error5  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::FeatureDetector::detect(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<class cv::KeyPoint,class std::allocator<class cv::KeyPoint> > &,class cv::Mat const &)const " (?detect@FeatureDetector@cv@@QBEXABVMat@2@AAV?$vector@VKeyPoint@cv@@V?$allocator@VKeyPoint@cv@@@std@@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function _main   
Error6  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SURF::SURF(double,int,int,bool,bool)" (??0SURF@cv@@QAE@NHH_N0@Z) referenced in function _main
Error7  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::FeatureDetector::~FeatureDetector(void)" (??1FeatureDetector@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall cv::Feature2D::~Feature2D(void)" (??1Feature2D@cv@@UAE@XZ)
Error8  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::DescriptorExtractor::~DescriptorExtractor(void)" (??1DescriptorExtractor@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall cv::Feature2D::~Feature2D(void)" (??1Feature2D@cv@@UAE@XZ)
Error9  error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

It didn't show me the error when i write code in VS2010 , but it show me error when i debug it , and can i use the same code for video

Comment: Have you build OpenCV in debug ? If so, check the linker's dependencies in the debug mode properties.

Comment: Yes i build it first , than debug it

Comment: Again, "check the linker's dependencies in the debug mode properties"

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: i just turn myself from python to VS and opencv

Comment: Right click on your project in the solution explorer, properties, linker editor, general, now compare additional libs line between the two configurations release and debug, my guess is that it isn't set for the debug mode. Just copy what is in release into debug.

Comment: No , it run my other opencv programs , its giving error in just this one

Comment: @CTZStef I add sanpshot for you

Comment: Well there's obviously something wrong with the linker regarding features2d... beside, the line I was talking about is in link editor / general. GL

Comment: I didnt find anything name editor here

Comment: @CTZStef I hope the above snapshot is helpful ,

Comment: I didn't install any library for it , do it need to download any header or .cpp for Surf ? i just have opencv 2.4.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surf is non free that's why error's occur ,

it needed the following additions:

```
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"   // SURF is nonfree
```

before doing anything else in main():

```
cv::initModule_nonfree();
```

and ofc link to opencv_nonfree244.lib

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` and make sure the list contains the path to your opencv library installation path. This should resemble `<\path\to\opencv\build>\lib\`.

Go to `Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` and then paste the following library names as dependencies in the debug configuration:

```
opencv_core244d.lib
opencv_highgui244d.lib
opencv_imgproc244d.lib
opencv_features2d244d.lib
```

and the following in release configuration:

```
opencv_core244.lib
opencv_highgui244.lib
opencv_imgproc244.lib
opencv_features2d244.lib
```

Comment: `Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SURF::SURF(void)" (??0SURF@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main`
`Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SURF::SURF(double,int,int,bool,bool)" (??0SURF@cv@@QAE@NHH_N0@Z) referenced in function _main`
`Error 3 error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals`

Comment: Still getting 3 error's , do i need to install any cpp or hpp file manually ?

Comment: I just noticed you've used `#pragma comment(lib,...)`. Try adding this line `#pragma comment(lib ,"opencv_features2d244.lib")`

Comment: In debug configuration, make it `#pragma comment(lib ,"opencv_features2d244d.lib")`

Comment: `Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file '#pragma comment(lib ,\opencv_features2d244d.lib\).obj'`

Comment: Don't add the line in the project properties. I meant for you to add it into your code, along with the other `#pragma comment(lib,...)` lines.